# Leave desktop visible but lock it

Tags: windows, software-rec, desktop

I am looking for a tool to lock my desktop (Windows) but leave the actual windows or at least snapshot of them visible.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Make a screenshot and set it as the login background?

Answer (score 6):

Stick to [Transparent Screen Lock PRO](http://www.e-motional.com/TScreenLock.htm) - the PRO version is much better than the base version.  "Lock My PC" is not really a professional program and I was able to defeat it quite easily.

Transparent Screen Lock uses the user's actual username and password and does not store a password like Lock My PC does so it is much more secure.

Answer (score 4):

**[Lock My PC](http://www.fspro.net/lock-pc/)** (shareware, S29.95) features custom lock screens and transparent lock screen options - your computer can be used as a presentation machine - the screen displays pictures or video, but nobody can touch your computer.

... and much more.

**[Transparent Screen Lock](http://www.e-motional.com/TScreenLock.htm)** (shareware, from $24.95) enables  IT professionals to prevent unauthorized system access, while maintaining the ability to view applications running on the desktop for monitoring purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Vista/Win7 Bubbles screen saver. Set require password to resume. For XP here is directions and download link. If you don't want the bubbles you can tweak to 1 small bubble or something.

http://www.bridgetonova.com/2007/08/how-to-install-vista-bubble-screen.html

Look for other screen savers like rain or snow that still show the desktop  just a little messy.

Comment: can I have a key combination to lock the screen and start the screensaver?

Comment: This stopped working in Windows 8 due to Microsoft deliberately disabling screensavers drawing over desktop in Windows 8 because they had a problem doing that in the Metro interface.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is called [Kiosk Mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/kiosk-mode/kiosk-mode). It has existed since XP and still exists in Windows 11. It's the only official and secure way to do what you want.

Specifically in **Assigned access single-app kiosk**:

> A single-app kiosk uses the assigned access feature to run a single
> app above the lock screen. When the kiosk account signs in, the app is
> launched automatically. The person using the kiosk cannot do anything
> on the device outside of the kiosk app.

There are other kiosk modes, like Assigned access multi-app kiosk, that can allow the user to have a locked down desktop but this is harder to configure and secure. I recommend using the single-app mode.